# Trying to show messages from database but they don't show up

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem cause I'm testing a messaging program but it doesn't work.
I want to show the conversations of the user but evreything stays blank.
This is the code:

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
include_once('functions.php');
$user_one = "13";
$db = safe_db_open($host, $gebruiker, $wachtwoord, $database);
$query= ("SELECT u.user_id,c.c_id,u.username,u.email
 FROM conversation c, users u
 WHERE CASE 
 WHEN c.user_one = '$user_one'
 THEN c.user_two = u.user_id
 WHEN c.user_two = '$user_one'
 THEN c.user_one= u.user_id
 END 
 AND (
 c.user_one ='$user_one'
 OR c.user_two ='$user_one'
 )
 Order by c.c_id DESC Limit 20");

$result = safe_query($db, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $c_id=$row['cid'];
 $user_id=$row['user_id'];
 $username=$row['username'];
 $email=$row['email'];
 $cquery= ("SELECT R.cr_id,R.time,R.reply FROM conversation_reply R WHERE R.c_id_fk='$c_id' ORDER BY R.cr_id DESC LIMIT 1");
 $cresult = safe_query($db, $cquery);
 $crow= mysqli_fetch_array($cresult);
 $cr_id=$crow['cr_id'];
 $reply=$crow['reply'];
 $time=$crow['time']; 
 echo "$time : $reply";
}
```

Comment: Any error messages? Did you check your SQL statements directly with a client?

Comment: @andy there doesn't shows up any errors that's why i'm confused

Comment: What about the queries?

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 okay now i did and it doesn't shows any errors...

Comment: how do you mean? @Arif_suhail_123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
include_once('functions.php');
$user_one = "13";
$db = safe_db_open($host, $gebruiker, $wachtwoord, $database);
$query= ("SELECT u.user_id, c.c_id, u.username, u.email
 FROM conversation c, users u
 WHERE CASE 
 WHEN c.user_one = '{$user_one}'
 THEN c.user_two = u.user_id
 WHEN c.user_two = '{$user_one}'
 THEN c.user_one = u.user_id
 END 
 AND (
 c.user_one = '{$user_one}'
 OR c.user_two ='{$user_one}'
 )
 ORDER BY c.c_id DESC LIMIT 20");

$result = safe_query($db, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $c_id = $row[cid];
 $user_id = $row[user_id];
 $username = $row[username];
 $email = $row[email];
 $cquery = ("SELECT R.cr_id, R.time, R.reply FROM conversation_reply R WHERE R.c_id_fk='{$c_id}' ORDER BY R.cr_id DESC LIMIT 1");
 $cresult = safe_query($db, $cquery);
 $crow = mysqli_fetch_array($cresult);
 $cr_id = $crow[cr_id];
 $reply = $crow[reply];
 $time = $crow[time]; 
 echo "$time : $reply";
}
?>
```

**BUT:**
What is that R in $cquery?
If it should to be "conversation_reply R" like name of cell in DB, try do this:

after include functions.php add this:

```
$helpvar = "conversation_reply R";
```

and then change $cquery to this:

```
$cquery= ("SELECT R.cr_id, R.time, R.reply FROM '{$helpvar}' WHERE R.c_id_fk='$c_id' ORDER BY R.cr_id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: maybe it is possible to just remove the R i guess

Comment: i find the solution it whas not what you said but thanks for the help.

Comment: @joske_saalfeld If this is not the solution, why mark it as such?